# reading multiple lines from inputstream socket Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, client-server, inputstream

I want to read multiple lines from an inputstream socket.

```
public void sendAsync(HashSet<Socket> socketHashset, Vector<String> vectors, 
PrintWriter printwriter) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    service.execute(() -> {
        for(Socket v : socketHashset){
            //this.printwriter =  new PrintWriter(v.getOutputStream(),true);
            for(String str: vectors ){
                this.printwriter.println(str);
                this.printwriter.flush();
            }
        }
    });
    /* Receiver */

    while(true){
        try {
             printWriter.println(keybordScanner.nextLine())
             while(scannerBuffer.hasNextLine()){
                 System.out.println(scannerBuffer.nextLine());
             }
        } catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the compiler is blocking then is checking "hasNextLine"

```
while(scannerBuffer).hasNextLine())
```

How can i solutionate this issue? some alternatives.

Comment: scannerBuffer is simple Scanner

Comment: What is the issue? I guess you _want_ hasNextLine to be checked? Unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

scannerBuffer.hasNextLine() will not return false if there is no next line, but will wait for a line, in which case will return true, or for the socket to close, in which case it will return an exception. If you want your program to be able to do something else while waiting for input, make a Thread for reading input. The thread will be blocked while waiting for input, but the rest of your program won't.

```
Thread readingThread=new Thread(new readFromSock(scannerBuffer));
readingThread.start();
```

and make another class:

```
class readFromSock implements Runnable{
    Scanner scannerBuffer;
    public readFrom(Scanner scan){
        scannerBuffer=scan;
    }
    public void run(){
        try {
             while(scannerBuffer.hasNextLine()){
                 System.out.println(scannerBuffer.nextLine());
             }
         } catch(NoSuchElementException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```